# taglib VB.net setup

Tags: vb.net, taglib

How do I set up taglib to use? (imports etc.)
I downloaded taglib-1.6.3 and have it in a folder in my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the Windows release (http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.0.3.7/taglib-sharp-2.0.3.7-windows.zip). Extract the files from the Libraries folder and you should see:

- policy.2.0.taglib-sharp.config
- policy.2.0.taglib-sharp.dll
- taglib-sharp.dll

Put these in some folder in your project and add a reference to them in your project (right click -> add reference -> .NET -> browse). Autocomplete should work out the right imports for you, but at a guess I'd try:

```
Imports TagLib.Id3v2
```

All the source is included so you should be able to work it out mostly from there.